# New result won't show in the console after assigning a new amount

Tags: python

I would like to create a account management. In doing so, I would like to create the following:

1. It should show the amount from the account, even after updating the new amount.
2. It should not be possible to overdraw the account.
3. It should no longer be possible to deposit or withdraw a negative amount.

This is how my account.txt file looks like:

```
1, Max Mustermann, 1080.0
2, Nora Mustermann, 790.0
3, Tomas Mustermann, 400.0
```

This is my problem: I can assign and payout an amount to a customer with my method, but the if i want to check out the new amount it will not output the new result in the console. For example:

```
Which account do you want to use?
 [1]  Max Mustermann
 [2]  Nora Mustermann
 [3]  Tomas Mustermann
 [0]  End
 Your input: 1

[1] Account Balance 
[2] Deposit 
[0] Change account
 Your Input: 1
 The account balance from  Max Mustermann is 1080.0 $

[1] Account Balance 
[2] Deposit 
[0] Change account
 Your Input: 2
 Your deposit: 20
 The account balance of account Max Mustermann is 1100.00 $

[1] Account Balance 
[2] Deposit 
[0] Change account
 Your Input: 1
 The account balance from  Max Mustermann is 1080.0 $ #´-> This schould be 1100.00$ and not 1080.0$
```

```
data = {}
input_first = ""

def show_which_account():
    global input_first

    with open("Account.txt") as f:
        print("Which account do you want to use?")
        for folder in f:
            list = folder.split(",")
            account_number = int(list[0])
            name = list[1]
            data[account_number] = list[1:]
            print(f" [{account_number}] {name}")

    print(" [0]  End")
    input_first = input(" Your input: ")
    acc_management()

def acc_management():
    global input_first

    if input_first == 0:
        exit()
```

```
    else:
        input_first = int(input_first)
        while input_first in data:
            credit2 = data[input_first][1]
            name2 = data[input_first][0]

            with open('Account.txt', 'r') as file:
                filedata = file.read()

            print("\n[1] Account Balance \n[2] Deposit \n[0] Change account")
            execution = int(input(" Your Input: "))

            if execution == 1:
                print(f" The account balance from {name2} is {credit2.strip()} $")

            elif execution == 2:
                deposit = float(input(" Your deposit: "))
                while deposit < 0:
                    try:
                        deposit = float(input(" Your deposit is negative. Add a new one: "))
                    except TypeError:
                        pass
                amount_e = float(credit2) + float(deposit)
                print(f" The account balance of account{name2} is {amount_e:.2f} $")
                filedata = filedata.replace(str(credit2), str(amount_e) + '\n')
                with open('Account.txt', 'w') as file:
                    file.write(filedata)
            else:
                show_which_account()
                break

show_which_account()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a deposit is made, you update the data file with the new balance, but you don't update the dictionary `data`. The dictionary is synchronized with the file with each call to the function `show_which_account`, but as long as the user performs operations on a single account, the active function is `acc_management`, and the dictionary `data` is never updated.

A simple solution: just update the dictionary `data` with the new balance after a deposit is made.

Comment: How can I customize this in the code?

Comment: After the line: `amount_e = float(credit2) + float(deposit)`, try adding the line: `data[input_first][1] = amount_e`.